# How to do lookup table for roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table that lists authors;

```
column :name, :string,
column :role_id, :integer
```

I have a table for the roles

```
column :role_name, :string
```

Models:

```
Author

belongs_to :role

Role

has_many :authors
```

This seems strange. Is it correct that  Author has one role and a role belongs to many authors?

Now if I have an author I now i can do the following;

`@author.name` and get the name.

How do I get the role_name

```
@author.role.role_name?
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please format your question correctly using four-space indenting or backticks as well as formatting your question neatly using the markdown style tags provided. Thanks.

Comment: whats the purpose of the role model? Is it for authorization purposes on just a description?

Comment: Its for authorization.  I thought that breaking the roles out into another model and table would give me flexibility down the road for adding more roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your associations are correct - look at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs_to-and-has_one) for explanation.
Also, you answered your own question, getting the role name for an author can be done with

```
@author.role.role_name
```

Another option would be to add the following line to the Author model

```
delegate :role_name, :to => :role
```

and then you would be able to get the role name simply with

```
@author.role_name
```

Comment: Thanks Eugen. That is exactly what I am going to do, you are a rock star.